# How to disable `Fit Page` while navigating bookmarks in Foxit Reader?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks, table-of-contents, foxit-reader

I can't navigate `PDF` document with Foxit Reader because each time I click bookmark entry, it drops any my early set zoom to `Fit Page` instead. I need to re-zoom each time. If I open bookmark entry property I see

[image]

Is it possible to disable this bag-o-feature?

Answer (score 1):

#### Each time I click bookmark entry, it drops any my early set zoom to Fit Page instead.

> 1. Open Foxit Reader / PhantomPDF.
> 2. Go to File menu, choose Preferences.
> 3. Find the Page Display tab, check the option Forbid the change of the current Zoom factor during execution of 'Go to Destination"
>    actions (these actions can be launched from bookmarks).
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Click Ok to apply the change.

Source: [Whenever I change pages via bookmarks, my zoom level changes, why? – Help Center | Foxit Software](https://kb.foxitsoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040240712-Whenever-I-change-pages-via-bookmarks-my-zoom-level-changes-why-)